# Are these two characterizations equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and let $M_X$ be a sigma algebra on X.

Let $Y$ be a topological space and let $M_Y$ be a Borel Sigma algebra of $Y$.

Let $f$ be a function which masp $X$ into $Y$.

Then, are these two equivalent?

(1) For every open set $U$ in Y, $f^{-1}(U)\in M_X$

(2) For every set $K\in M_Y$, $f^{-1}(K)\in M_X$

Clearly, (2) implies (1) since every open set is a Borel set.

But, does (1) also imply (2)?

Intuitively, it sounds true because every Borel set is generated by "infinite" number of operations of union,intersection,complement on open sets.

But, is it indeed true and how can one prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume (1). Show that
$$
\mathcal{E}:=\{K\subseteq Y\mid f^{-1}(K)\in M_X\}
$$
is a sigma algebra that contains all open sets. Then use the fact that the Borel sigma algebra $M_Y$ is the sigma algebra generated by all open sets to conclude that $\mathcal{E}$ contains $M_Y$.

Comment: Okay! I worked it out and I got it!